# extracts data from cube sometimes fails

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssas

I have a scheduled job running every minutes, extracting data from a cube into a table (writing mdx in ssis).

In 99% of the time, it works fine.

However, sometimes it failed randomly.

I am using Microsift OLE DB Provider for Analysis Service 11.0 / 9.0 (10.0 not working all the time).

Here are some error msg:

Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E05.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server 2012 Analysis Services."  Hresult: 0x00000001  Description: "Error Code = 0x80040E05, External Code = 0x00000000:.

xx failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202009.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE

Heaps of thanks in advence,

ry

Comment: You appear to be creating multiple accounts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621813/sometimes-failed-when-extract-from-a-cube#comment38157293_24621813 . I wouldn't do that unless you want to get banned.

Comment: It's not just a previous post, it's a previous post under another account...

Comment: Question still contains too little information to help you. SSIS is hard enough to debug with it in front of you, let alone remotely....